# using Image Manipulation Class in CodeIgniter 4 without save in a file

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

this is my code

```
$file = new \CodeIgniter\Files\File($imgUrl);
$fileMime = $file->getMimeType();

if(file_exists("img/us/".$_SESSION["sess_order"]."/".$_SESSION["sess_userimg"])){
  if($fileMime == 'image/jpeg'){
    $image = \Config\Services::image()
      -> withFile($file)
      -> fit(100, 100, 'center');

    header("Content-type: image/JPEG");
    echo $image;
  }
}else{
  return "img/usr.png";
  
}
```

I'll get user's Image and return thumbnail of that image.
with Image Manipulation Class in #CodeIgniter 4 can do it well, but I don't need to save thumbnail file in storage, I just need image as an Object. How can I do it.
I want something like using file_get_contents() function and return it
thanks

Comment: If you are showing the image on the screen, you need to load it from somewhere, which means it needs to be saved first. You can delete it after the page loads, but that would mean the user will loose it on leaving the page.

Comment: I have an image in disk, it is 800X800 , but I want to load this image in 60X60, But don't save this little one in hard disk, just to show it. somthing like user image in facebook, you see thumbnail in every user's post. now I want to use one big image and load it in every size that I need, but not save that thumbnail in memory.